# FB.getLoginStatus doesn't work in Chrome even sandbox disable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I follow railscast to add "sign in with Facebook" feature in my site, there is no problem to login. But when try to logout, it seems that FB.getLoginStatus never got fire even when I disable Sandbox Mode in facebook developer app settings (as suggested in some other discussion):

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
return $.ajax({
  url: "" + window.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js",
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true
});
});

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId: 'xxxxxomittedxxxxx',
  cookie: true,
  status: true,
  xfbml: true,
  oauth: true
    });
$('#sign_in').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      return window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback';
    }
  });
});
return $('#sign_out').click(function(e) {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      return FB.logout(response.authResponse);
    }
  });
  return true;
});
 };

}).call(this);
```

The reason I know the FB.getLoginStatus never get in (or doesn't work) is I replace the body with:

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    return alert("I am here!");
  });
```

and I cannot see my alert while "sign_out" click.

I am running both Chrome and Firefox having the same behaviour. Could anybody help to spot what am I missing? Thanks a lot.

Let me describe more specific about the "behaviour" I encountered:

1. sign in with Facebook from mysite.com the first time a Facebook login window will popup and ask for email and password, and I can sign in to my site perfectly ok and work as expected
2. then I click on sign_out button from mysite.com/users/1, it looks like it sign out ok.
3. then sign in with Facebook from mysite.com again, now it won't popup the Facebook login window anymore and login to mysite.com/users/1 directly without asking email and password!
4. if I open another browser window and go to facebook.com and logout from there, then when I sign in with Facebook from mysite.com, it will popup a Facebook login window now and ask for my email and password.

I would like my site to behave: "when logout from mysite.com/users/n and sign in with Facebook again from mysite.com, the Facebook login window shall popup"

Anyone could be of help? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**

Further investigation found the "root" cause might be still: the sign out is under the different route (or page) of the sign in route and FB.getLoginStatus just cannot be fire under the mysite.com/signout. The error message from firebug indicates that "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

To proof it is the route issue, I put a sign out link in the same route (page) as sign in route which is the root route mysite.com as specified in the "Website with Facebook Login", everything works and can logout as expected:

```
<%= link_to "sign out facebook", "#" , id: "sign_out" %>
```

by the way the sign_out js is revised to get rid of FB.logout(response.authResponse) uncaught [object Object] error, because FB.logout expects function as parameter:

```
return $('#sign_out').click(function(e) {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      FB.logout();
    }
  }, true);
});
};
```

So, the bottom line: FB.getLoginStatus might still have a bug which cannot handle the call from a different route than sign in route. (I tested with Chrome, Firefox and Safari and all behave the same but not true for IE10. Somehow IE10 works even sign out at different route.)

Any comment from people who have similar problem? Please advise. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding true as second parameter to getLoginStatus, as stated in FB dev doc:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
}, true);
```

This should avoid caching.
Another option is to subscribe to events:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  // do something with response
});
```

All from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

Comment if you have questions.

**EDIT:**

I modified your script a little bit, removed unneeded code parts. You had too many returns that are not needed. I tried sign out within this modified script, it works as you need it.
Events subscription is for check purposes.

```
<head>
    <title>Exam entry</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <input type="button" value="Sign in" id="sign_in" />
    <input type="button" value="Sign out" id="sign_out" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '586844044669652',
                cookie: true,
                status: true,
                xfbml: true
            });


            // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
            // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
            // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
            // will be handled. 
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
                    // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
                    // have logged in to the app.
                    testAPI();
                } /*else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
                    // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
                    // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
                    // like this, for two reasons:
                    // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
                    // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
                    // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
                    FB.login();
                } else {
                    // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
                    // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
                    // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
                    // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
                    // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
                    FB.login();
                }*/
            });


            $('#sign_in').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        //return window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback';
                    }
                });
            });
            $('#sign_out').click(function (e) {
                FB.logout(function (response) {
                    console.log("Here logout response", response);
                });
            });

        };

        // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
        // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
        }

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, tried both but same behaviour. Still cannot get in and do something with response. In my case I cannot FB.logout.

Comment: Thanks a gain for your help. I tried your js. It behaves the same as before and with one extra error message: FB.logout() called without an access token.

Comment: Please refer the full page at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533763/fb-getloginstatus-doesnt-work-at-domain-signout-route)